# How does Disruptor Barriers work?

Tags: disruptor-pattern

How does LMX disruptor's barrier work? I do understand how to use disruptor with DSL. But I could not found a good reference for how a barrier or sequence barriers work.

e.g. I found following link, but not sure how to use Barrier data strcture. 
http://mechanitis.blogspot.com/2011/08/dissecting-disruptor-why-its-so-fast.html

For example, new BatchEventProcessor() accepts a SequenceBarrier. Why? and how can I create one.

Comment: Hopefully this helps, they are actually related conceptually but at very different layers of the stack.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly - a memory barrier is a CPU architecture primitive; a SequenceBarrier is an implementation class in the Disruptor. I will attempt to cover both.

Memory barrier - allows software to provide instruction to hardware that all instructions before a certain point X must have been completed before X is. This is used because CPUs  provide out-of-order execution optimisations. For more details, best to read this paper - See [Memory Barriers: a Hardware View for Software Hackers](http://www.rdrop.com/users/paulmck/scalability/paper/whymb.2009.04.05a.pdf).

SequenceBarrier is an implementation class in the Disruptor; generally speaking it is a part of the Disruptor and you won't need to use it outside the Disruptor. It actually performs a similar function conceptually to a memory barrier - it prevents consumers getting ahead of a publisher on the ringbuffer.
See - [SequenceBarrier on github](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lmax/disruptor/SequenceBarrier.java).

Comment: Thanks Json!! When creating BatchEventProcessor, it needs a SequenceBarrier, which forces us to create a SequenceBarrier.Thats why I wanted to understand.   Should I just take the barrier from CircularBuffer via newBarrier. But that would not work if I want to use BatchEventProcessor not at first, but as second or third handler (e.g. via then)

Comment: Have you tried using the DSL? Check here - https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/wiki/Disruptor-Wizard